# Modify a HTML file based off google doc/spreed sheet to embed instagram

Tags: html, google-sheets, instagram, google-docs

I am rather new to this so please forgive me if this is obvious or makes no sense. Basically I have not been able to find a way to embed a Instagram page's feed like you can with Twitter or Facebook. The only way I have found are by going through a third party site that either takes up the full page or is a monthly subscription. I am trying to have a html file with a script that pulls a set of 2 links from a google spreed sheet or google doc and uploads them into a link and image tags with out having to go in and modify the HTML file every time. I am current taking the source link from instagram and the image link and creating a linked image with them. I am then displaying that file in a iframe.  This was my attempt at a hopefully simple work around and would like to know if it is possible. This is what I currently have as the basic set up.

```
<a target="_parent" href="##link##">
  <img class="image" src="##link##" style="height:auto; width:100%;">
</a>
```

My thought process was that if I could connect either a google sheet or doc I could use a script with something like this.

```
<a id="1" target="_parent" href=""><img id="1" class="image" src="" style="height:auto; width:100%;"></a>   
<a id="2" target="_parent" href=""><img id="2" class="image" src="" style="height:auto; width:100%;"></a> 
<script> 
var linkA = a, linkB = b, L2=1, L1=1;
for(a=0; a<100; a++){
document.getElementById(L1).src = [A(L1)]; //not sure if this is the proper way to locate the coordinates from the sheet
L1++;}
for(b=0; b<100; b++){
document.getElementById(L2).href = [B(L2)];
L2++;}
</script>
```

The issue I have run into is how to get the data from the sheet and then the proper way to use the data in a script to run have it replace the links. Ideally I would be able to simply add the two links into the sheet and the script would load them on to the page next time it loads.

Comment: Welcome to SO maybe you can share some of your code that you already made?

Comment: @j.vee I have added some code and hopefully made it a little clearer what I am trying to achieve.